# Making the results from function a string

Tags: import, python-3, function, dictionary, values

I am trying to get the features count from feature, then put it in a dictionary that I can call later:

```
ct_dict = dict()
...
fipsList = ['13245','06007']
for fip in fipsList: 
    mergedJoinCentroids = C:/Workspace/Sandbox/MapChangeProject/selects.gdb/mergeJoinCentroids_{}".format(fip)
    property_ct = str(arcpy.GetCount_management(mergedJoinCentroids))
    ct_dict.setdefault(fip, property_ct)
```

I tried to make a simple function that I could then easily import into another script:

```
def ct_dict():
   return ct_dict
```

This should return a dictionary that looks like this `{'13245': '72456', '06007': '93557'}`.However, I run the other script with the `ct_dict()` function, I get an error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'`:

```
import <script name>
from <script name> import ct_dict
...
counts = ct_dict()
...
for k, v in ct_dict.items():
    if fip == v:
       sheet1.write(r, propertyCol, v)
```

So, basically, it is just returning something like this `<function FEMA_WMS_3.ct_dict()>`, not a dictionary. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to create and object instead of a function. When you're looking for ct_dict.items() it's going to the function ct_dict and looking for a items() method. There isn't one.

It should be;

```
for k, v in counts.items():
   if fip ==v:
     etc...
```